# Traefik always servs default certificate

Tags: certificate, traefik

Traefik 2.2.8 always servs the default certificate with this configuration:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":8001"

[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/[...]/x1.y1.z1.crt"
  keyFile = "/x1.y1.z1.key"

[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/[...]/x2.y2.z2.crt"
  keyFile = "/[...]/x2.y2.z2.key"

<a dozen more certificates>

[http.routers.1]
 entryPoints = ["https"]
  service = "1"
  rule = "Host(`x1.y1.z1`)"

[http.routers.1.tls]
  [[http.routers.1.tls.domains]]
    sans = ["x1.y1.z1"]

[http.services.1]
  [http.services.1.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.1.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://internal:10012"
```

I migrated from V1 so I am sure the certificates work. And even adding SANs for the router doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

All certificates have to be stored in a special file that is loaded with the File Provider.